# Javascript dropdown buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, dropdown

I've created a drop down box which contains effects to filter an image.

I want drop down 1 to be linked to drop down 2 box using java script.

HTML code for dropdown 1 is:

```
<select id="areaImageEffects" onchange="" style="height: 30px;"> 
    <option value="Grayscale">Grayscale</option> 
    <option value="Threshold"> Threshold</option>
</select>
```

Html code for dropdown 2 is:

```
<select id="ImageEffectsProperties" onchange="" style="height: 30px;"> 
    <option value="Greyscale1">Greyscale1</option> 
    <option value="Greyscale2">Greyscale2</option>
</select>
```

Can someone help me link the two drop downs together using Javascript so that when I make a selection on drop down 1, drop down 2 should appear.

Comment: You dont want to link the dropdowns but you want to show the other after a selection in the first Dropdown right?

If so hide dropdown2 on pageload. Then in the onchange event of dropdown1 write a function that shows dropdown2. 
 `function showDropdown2(){
document.getElementById('ImageEffectsProperties').style.visibilty = 'visible';}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call function through `onchange` event such that `onchange = "myFunction()"`
And write the below script.

```
<script>
//hide dropdown2 on page load.
document.getElementById('ImageEffectsProperties').style.visi‌​bilty = 'hidden';

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('ImageEffectsProperties').style.visi‌​bilty = 'visible';
}
</script>
```